# Can chisel implement printf to a file?

Tags: chisel

Chisel provides the printf function for debugging purposes, when generating verilog, it becomes fwrite system function. How to use verilog simulation to output data to a file instead of the terminal only when the chisel code is modified. Can chisel's printf function do this?

Comment: I don't think it can. I thought I remembered hearing some discussion of this but I'm struggling to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer appears to be no. But there are two issues filed about this

[Can chisel implement printf to a file? #1290](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues/1290)

[Feature Request: Allow printfs to go to different file descriptors #1287](https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/issues/1287)

It might be a good PR to submit.